# Understanding shadowing in rust

Tags: rust

I'm on a journey learning rust at my own pace. I'm primarily a C++, Python programmer.
Instead of just following the manual, I try to do weird things in the language and understand the behaviour.

I'm experimenting with the concept of shadowing variables in rust. Can I get an understanding of why this program prints 1 continuously?

```rust
fn main() {
    let counter = 0;

    let counter = loop{
        let counter = counter + 1;
        println!("{}", counter);
        if counter == 10{
            break counter *  2;
        }
    };
    println!("The result is {}", counter);
}
```

Here is what I thought would occur. I haven't yet tried it in debugger though.

1. counter is initialized and assigned 0.
2. the loop is run,

   2.1 counter will be incremented by 1.

   2.2 it will print 1.

   2.3 check if counter is 10, if it is so, break with counter * 2, this will be returned out of the loop.

   2.4 else, just continue...
3. counter is now 20.
4. print "The result is 20"

I'd expect to see:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

The result is 20
```

What I get:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
.. and so on
```

Is it that shadowing reinitializes the named variable to 0? That is what occurs here..

Comment: On each iteration counter is reset to 0, because shadowing creates a new variable scoped to current iteration.

Comment: This looks more like a game than a real reasonable code.

Comment: It is a light variation over the loops code in [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
    let counter = 0;
    let counter = loop{
        let counter = counter + 1;
        ...
    }
```

At any iteration, you're starting from a new scope, the previous version doesn't exist. The right part of the `let counter = counter + 1;` assignment always refer to the outside `counter`, which is always 0.

Comment: "At any iteration, you're starting from a new scope," Aha! now it makes sense.